# How to init vector<array<char, 5>>?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
array<char, 5> d{"sdfd"};
```

works

```
 vector<array<char, 5>> s1{{"asdf"}};
```

compilation error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::array<char, 5ul> >::vector(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’     vector<array<char, 5>> s1{{"asdf"}};
```

compilation:  g++ -std=c++11 ./test.cc

linux gcc 5.4.0

how to fix?

Comment: what compiler are you using? cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/Wb4eh33Tq

Comment: Does `array<char, 5> s1{"asdf"}` work for you?

Comment: yes, it works for me

Comment: `vector<array<char, 5>> s1{array<char, 5>{"asdf"}};`

Comment: it works, thank you

Comment: @Eugene answers go down below 

Comment: @康桓瑋 answers go down below 

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Try before 11.1.